# No linear graph patterns in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the Cypher documentation I only see "linear" graph patterns. For example:

```
MATCH a --> b --> c <-- d
RETURN a
```

It is possible to create "no linear" graph patterns as I used to do in SPARQL? For example:

```
SELECT ?a
WHERE {
   ?a :p ?b .
   ?a :q ?c .
   ?a :r ?d
}
```

By "linear" I means that degree in the pattern is less or equal than 2.

It is possible to create no linear patterns in Cypher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply separate the patterns with commas:

```
MATCH 
    a --> b,
    a --> c,
    a --> d
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE 
    a-[:p]->b AND 
    a-[:q]->c AND
    a-[:r]->d
RETURN a
```